# Device communication behind gateway

Tags: device, device-management

Where can I find sample code for implementing the Azure IoT Hub Device Management features? Looking at https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks there doesn't seem to be any samples on this.

Comment: How about [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks#samples)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are at the right repo but the DM additions are currently in a different branch called 'dmpreview'. Select this on Github and you will see in de csharp sample a new project in the 'GetStartedWithIoTHubDM' folder for example.